# Remove duplicate observations when sample IDs are in two columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

The dataset I am working with has similarity values between all individuals in a dataframe. In total there are 80 samples and so the dataframe has 6,400 rows. I am trying to generate a new group ID for all samples that have values greater than 0.15 together and remove duplicated comparisons.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
ID.1  ID.2 Similarity   
GL15   GL1 0.215385
GL15  GL23 0.273504
GL15  GV21 0.254717
GL15   GV3 0.252174
GV21  GL23 0.243243
GV21   GV3 0.284404
GV21   GV7 0.186047
GV21  LL12 0.191176
GV21  LL14 0.230769
GV21  LL15 0.178947
GV21   LL2 0.264151
LV19   GV7 0.204225
LV11   GV8 0.323232
LV15   GV8 0.281818
LL8    GV3 0.200000
GV18   GV4 0.224359
LL12   GV4 0.219355
LL7    GV5 0.292683
GL14   GV5 0.262712
```

I would like to add a column or break this into smaller dataframes where all samples that share similarity are put into a group and duplicate entries removed. The output would look like

```
ID.1  ID.2 Similarity   Group
GL15   GL1 0.215385 A
GL15  GL23 0.273504 A
GL15  GV21 0.254717 A
GL15   GV3 0.252174 A
GV21  GL23 0.243243 A
GV21   GV3 0.284404 A
GV21   GV7 0.186047 A
GV21  LL12 0.191176 A
GV21  LL14 0.230769 A
GV21  LL15 0.178947 A
GV21   LL2 0.264151 A
LV19   GV7 0.204225 B
LV11   GV8 0.323232 C
LV15   GV8 0.281818 C
LL8    GV3 0.200000 A
GV18   GV4 0.224359 D
LL12   GV4 0.219355 A
LL7    GV5 0.292683 E
GL14   GV5 0.262712 E
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear how you're creating the groups as one `A` similarity is higher than `B`

Comment: Sorry about that, the subset I have provided only has samples above the 0.15 cutoff I wanted to use. The groups I am trying to produce reflect samples that have a high similarity to one another.  A better phrasing might be that I want to find all individuals similar to individual GL15.  This would include all of the individuals listed in the first 4 entries (that are obviously similar to individual GL15), but also those that are similar to individual GL21 because GL21 was seen to be similar to GL15.

Comment: What defines if they share similarity?

Comment: The similarity was already calculated. The dataset I have has 6400 entries with similarities ranging from 0.0014 to 1.0. I can easily reduce the dataset to those that are above the 0.15 cutoff; however, I am still left with trying to identify all of the samples similar to GL15 or similar to a sample also identified as similar to GL15.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

library(tidyverse)
data_example <- fread("
      ID1  ID2  similarity
      GL15 GL1 0.215385
      GL15 GL23 0.273504
      GL15 GV21 0.254717
      GL15 GV3 0.252174
      GV21 GL23 0.243243
      GV21 GV3 0.284404
      GV21 GV7 0.186047
      GV21 LL12 0.191176
      GV21 LL14 0.230769
      GV21 LL15 0.178947
      GV21 LL2 0.264151
      LV19 GV7 0.204225
      LV11 GV8 0.323232
      LV15 GV8 0.281818
      LL8 GV3 0.200000
      GV18 GV4 0.224359
      LL12 GV4 0.219355
      LL7 GV5 0.292683
      GL14 GV5 0.262712
      GV5  GL14 0.262712") %>% as_tibble


data_example_no_duplicates <- data_example %>%
  mutate(ID12 = map2(ID1,ID2,list) %>%
           map(unlist) %>% 
           map(sort) %>% 
           map_chr(reduce,str_c)) %>% 
  distinct(ID12,.keep_all = T)

those_similar_gl_15 <- data_example_no_duplicates %>% 
  filter(ID12 %>% str_detect("GL15"),similarity > 0.15) %>% 
  mutate(similar = ID12 %>% str_remove("GL15")) %>% 
  pull(similar)

data_example_no_duplicates %>% 
  filter(similarity > 0.15,
         ID1 %in% those_similar_gl_15| ID2 %in% those_similar_gl_15 |ID12 %>% str_detect("GL15"))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  ID1   ID2   similarity ID12    
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>   
1 GL15  GL1        0.215 GL1GL15 
2 GL15  GL23       0.274 GL15GL23
3 GL15  GV21       0.255 GL15GV21
4 GL15  GV3        0.252 GL15GV3 
5 GV21  GL23       0.243 GL23GV21
6 GV21  GV3        0.284 GV21GV3 
7 LL8   GV3        0.2   GV3LL8
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however, I really need to be able to find those similar to GL15.

Comment: It finds those similiar to GL15, just not those similar to those similar to GL15